# Couldn't add or remove programs using ubuntu software center (USC)in Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 12.04,currently.Recently ,I updated my system with update manager and downloaded USC from muon software center which was pre-installed  in this system. I could download a lot of softwares such as:
                         -firefox
                         -XBMC media center
                         -VLC media player
But when I tried to get some more softwares using USC, after rebooting there began the problem . It does not begin either downloading or instaling the program. When I tried to download  the same program using muon software center it showed the following:

```
                   Unable to obtain the package at this time
```

Another application seems to be using the package  system at this time. You must close all other package managers before you will be able to install or remove any packages.

I am quite sure that have closed USC . I tried to remove USC, assuming  that it caused the problem using muon software center but the result was same.Now I cannot add or remove any programs into my system & I don't know what to do . Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: are any other package manager opened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the dash and type system monitoring then from  process tab search for

> **software center**

then right click and press stop process

If you didn't find software center in process tab search for  **apt-get** or **dpkg**

Comment: you could also use this solution

Comment: no , there is no results for software center in process tab of system monitor

Comment: try seraching for `apt-get` or `dpkg`

Comment: yes, the only processes that i found on searching so  was

Answer (score 0):

try to see if any apt-* program is still running in the background by using :

```
ps ax | grep apt
```

Then kill the process by its pid:

```
sudo kill -9 [pid]
```

Comment: no that isn't working.it shows as follows in terminal when i tried this:                                               ERROR: garbage process ID "[pid]".
Usage:
  kill pid ...              Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
  kill signal pid ...       Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -s signal pid ...    Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -l                   List all signal names.
  kill -L                   List all signal names in a nice table.
  kill -l signal            Convert between signal numbers and names.

Comment: you should put the real process id (number) not the [pid] word

Comment: when you issue `ps ax | grep apt` you get a list of process using the apt command and then you can take process ids from the first column of each line

Comment: yes ,i also  tried using the process id ( like 2546 , 2546 )but its still the same

Comment: reboot your machine

Comment: yes ,it finally worked. i can never thank u enough for what u have done for me. It was the process  with pid-2535 that caused all this mess. thank u so much. it is much satisfying that the ubuntu community has so much support & care for its  users. once again my sincere thanks kamil.bye

Answer (score 0):

try to make `sudo apt-get update` from terminal then try it again if the above solution doesn't work